# page.FindControl returns Null when looking for FileUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webmethod

I'm trying to upload an image using FileUpload control using a WebMethod instead of a C# Method however I cannot find the control using the page.FindControl and it returns null.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="profile_pic_input" onchange="inputpic(this)" clientidmode="Static" type="file" accept="image/*"  runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
```

JS:

```
function inputpic() {
       PageMethods.UploadPicture(onSuccess, onFailure);
}
```

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UploadPicture()
{
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
           {
                    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
                    FileUpload uploader = new FileUpload();
                    uploader = (FileUpload)page.FindControl("profile_pic_input");

                    if (uploader.HasFile)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Has file!");
                    }
            }
}
```

It throws a NullReference Exception and when debugged, the 'uploader' object returns null and cannot find the asp control. What am I doing wrong? And yes the ASP page is allowed to use PageMethods through the ScriptManager.

Comment: try changing your Page page = line to the following 
`Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;`

Comment: can you post more of your HTML, if your fileupload control is inside another control that can be a problem, also if you are using a master page.

Comment: @MaCron No the control is independent and is not inside another control. I'm not using master pages either

Comment: Try replacing `page.FindControl` with `this.FindControl` or if you want to use page, don't redefine what it is, just use `Page.FindControl`